# How to transfer a list as a Python function argument

Tags: python, external-calls

This issue was already discussed here, but the answer is unclear yet.
I use very simple Python function for converting a string list to upper case

```python
def ListToUpper(wrd_lst):
  string_list=wrd_lst
  for i in range(len(wrd_lst)):
    string_list[i] =string_list[i].upper()
  return string_list
```

Code `ListToUpper(['a','b'])` works in Python as needed.
But Mathematica displays an error when one calls (`ss` -- session)

```
ExternalEvaluate[ss, <| "Command" -> "ListToUpper","Arguments" -> {"['a', 'b']"} |>]
```

It's strange, as the argument `['a', 'b']` is the same for both calls. In the case, when argument is a scalar (or string), all works properly

Comment: What error does it display? Please add it to the question.

Comment: "This issue was already discussed here, but the answer is unclear yet." Which post are you refering to? Can you add the link to the question?

Answer (score 5):

By taking advantage of Python's list comprehension capability, this method does not need to convert the tuple `wrd_list` to a list

```
ss = StartExternalSession["Python"]

listToUpper = ExternalFunction[ss, "def ListToUpper(wrd_lst):
     return [i.upper() for i in wrd_lst]"];

listToUpper[{"a", "b"}]

(*   {A, B}  *)
```

Comment: For me, it is desirable to use an external Python function, because I apply more comprehensive processing of a list (related to language stemming). I'm not sure that ExternalFunction will support external Python function in *.py file  :((

Comment: @Konstantin why wouldn't it support  that?  Can you `import` the file that exports the function you want?

Comment: The LouisB's code works fine for my problem of stemming.  But executing a Python file with ExternalEvaluate is more preferable for some reasons. For example, my Python file can include a number of functions, so they can be called by ExternalEvaluate[ss, <| "Command" -> "coms",  "Arguments" -> {args} |>] without definition of new ExternalFunction for each Python function

Comment: Thank you to all! The problem is solved by calling:   ExternalEvaluate[ss, File["PythonFile"]]; ExternalEvaluate[ss, <| "Command" -> "com",  
  "Arguments" -> {{arg1, arg2, ..., argn}} |>]

Answer (score 4):

This works fine:

```
ss = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ListToUpper = ExternalFunction[ss, "def ListToUpper(wrd_lst):
  string_list=list(wrd_lst)
  for i in range(len(wrd_lst)):
    string_list[i] = string_list[i].upper()
  return string_list"];

ListToUpper[{"a", "b"}]

(* {"A", "B"} *)
```

Note that I used `list(wrd_lst)` as `wrd_lst` is passed as a tuple and tuples are immutable later on at the point `string_list[i] = ...` so you must convert to a mutable list first.